# Flash banner is working if the page url have preceding "www" and not working if not

Tags: php, html, flash

I have a weird problem,
Flash banner is working "*clickable*" if the page url have preceding "**www**" and not working if not,

So the if the URL in the address bar was "*www*.example.com" the banner will be clickable and will redirect you to the link embedded in it, if the URL was "example.com" the flash banner will not be working.

*any ideas ?*

Comment: Maybe is a problem with that Flash movie. Does it have some AS code you can post?

Answer (score 0):

try putting this in the params while embedding the flash code,,

```
 allowscriptaccess="always"
```

and if you have not put the click tag then put

```
on (release) {
if (clickTAG.substr(0,4) == "http") {
getURL(clickTAG, '_blank');
}
}
```

refer to the below link for more details
http://support.qualityunit.com/knowledgebase/post-affiliate-pro/troubleshooting/flash-banner-is-not-clickable.html

Comment: I have tested the problem on many environments,
it is working on windows firefox with using www or without, but on firefox linux it is not working without using www, I think on Mac like linux also